# Can I change the timezone for my api from the server where it is stored? Azure API Manager

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, xml-to-json, liquid-template

I am using Azure API Manager with an api whose policy converts xml-to-json (done with a liquid template).
One of the tasks I have is that I need to make sure that the dates in my JSON object are in a certain timezone.
I have come across the below:

```
%Z  Time zone name
```

The closest server we have is Australia and I am trying to verify that each time it comes in NZST

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have learnt you cannot, you can only change the formatting of the datetime.

However during the conversion of xml-to-json the timezone is datetime is automatically formatted on what is used, for instance; GMT/UTC etc.

The backend or frontend can only control the timezone, Liquid templating cannot.